# Asymptotic values of integrals

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, asymptotics

For an integral like
$$D_{n}(x) \equiv \int_{0}^{x} \frac{t^{n}}{e^{t}-1} d t$$
The asymptotic values are given as

$$D_{n}(x) \simeq\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
n ! \zeta(n+1)-x^{n} e^{-x}+O\left(x^{n} e^{-2 x}\right), & x \rightarrow \infty \\
x^{n} / n-x^{n+1} / 2(n+1)+O\left(x^{n+2}\right), & x \rightarrow 0
\end{array}\right.$$

Is there a way to get these expressions in Mathematica?

Comment: For the $x=0$ series the following works `Assuming[n > 0, 
 Series[Integrate[t^n/(Exp[t] - 1), {t, 0, x}], {x, 0, 3}]]`.

Comment: By the way, you should type at least something in MA format to help others who are willing to help.

Answer (score 1):

As a starter:

```
Integrate[x^n/(-1 + E^x), {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, 
 Assumptions -> n \[Element] Integers && n > -1 && x \[Element] Reals]
```

[image]

(*   Integrate[x^n/(-1 + E^x), {x, -[Infinity], [Infinity]},
Assumptions -> n [Element] Integers && n > -1 && x [Element] Reals] *)

**For the solution →∞:**

```
IntSer[x_, n_] := 
 Integrate[Series[t^n /(Exp[t] - 1), {t, Infinity, 2}], {t, 0, x}]
Table[{n, IntSer[x, n], n! Zeta[n + 1] - x E^-x}, {n, 1, 
   2}] // TableForm
```

[image: without Normal]

This shows two aspects of the solution:
(1) Mathematica does not expand the same way as Your sources do.
(2) The condition seems to have higher validity.

The methods of Mathematica to not do the asymptotic expansion this is just the integral this way.

This result can be developed further into a asymptotic You will prefer. Reenter this with Normal:

```
Table[{n, Normal@IntSer[x, n], (n + 1)! Zeta[n + 1] - x E^-x}, {n, 1, 
   2}] // TableForm
```

[image: result more suitable for Your questions intent.]

The function freed from the condition can be expanded in Mathematica:

```
Series[\[Pi]^2/6 + x Log[1 - Cosh[x] + Sinh[x]] - 
  PolyLog[2, E^-x], {x, \[Infinity], 3}]
```

(* [image] *)

```
Series[x^2 Log[1 - Cosh[x] + Sinh[x]] - 2 x PolyLog[2, E^-x] - 
  2 PolyLog[3, E^-x] + 2 Zeta[3], {x, \[Infinity], 3}]
```

[image]

**For the solution x->0:**

```
IntSer0[x_, n_] := 
 Integrate[Series[t^n /(Exp[t] - 1), {t, 0, 3}], {t, 0, x}]
Table[{n, Normal@IntSer0[x, n], x^n/n - x^(n + 1)/(2 (n + 1))}, {n, 1,
    2}] // TableForm
```

[image]

In the expansion →0 this solution is expanded approximately and confirms the formula for n=1 and 2. The O can be confirmed expanding to n=2 and then drop the second-order term.

This does confirm ()≃. I hope Mathematica is correct and I discovered a typo in Your formula.

**Induction step symbolic for both:**

```
Integrate[t^n*SeriesData[t, 0, {1, -1/2, 1/12, 0, -1/720}, -1, 4, 1], {t, 0, x}]

Integrate[t^n (
SeriesData[t, 0, {1, 
Rational[-1, 2], 
Rational[1, 12], 0, 
Rational[-1, 720]}, -1, 4, 1]), {t, 0, x}, 
 Assumptions -> n \[Element] Integers && n > -1 && x \[Element] Reals]
```

The problem stems from the term t^(n-1) according to the information given in [`Integrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate.html).

Mathematica does not do this for arbitrary n in V12.0.0. Since the () formula is valid for all n and The approximation can be integrated for n to give n+1 up to a constant the induction step is done.

The opportunity to use a logarithmics substitution fails the same way as the direct integration:

```
u[t_] := Exp[-t]
D[u[t], t]
```

(*-Exp[-t]*)

du/dt=-Exp[-t] => du=-udt => -du/u=dt

or

```
t[u_] := -Log[u]
D[t[u], u]
```

(* -1/u *)

dt/du=-1/u => dt=-du/u

```
Integrate[(-Log[u])^n/(u (u - 1)), {u, 1, Exp[x]}]
```

[image]

But

```
Solve[1/(u (u - 1)) == B/u + 1/(u - 1), B]
```

(* {B->-1} *)

`dt = -du/ u` so the substitution has to be `(-Log[u])^ n/(u (u - 1))`!! This stems from `t[u_] := -Log[u],  D[t[u], u] is -  1/u`! The partial fraction decomposition is 1/(u (u - 1)) == -1/u +
1/(u - 1)!!!

```
Integrate[-(-Log[u])^n/u, {u, 1, Exp[x]}]

ConditionalExpression[-(((-x)^n x)/(1 + n)), 
 Re[x] <= 0 && Im[x] == 0 && Re[n] > -1]

Integrate[-(-Log[u])^n/(u - 1), {u, 1, Exp[x]}]
```

[image: does still not integrate universal for n]

This is again open for the asymptotic expansion of ().

Comment: It does not solve the original question. There is a big gap between solving for $n=1,2$ and a general case. Why do you even think $n$ is integer, there is no such assumption in OP?! Your remark at the end is about integer $n$.

Comment: This is the general solution with the induction step that is not conducted by Mathematica. Now, why do I expect this to be n? This looks like [Poisson distribution moment](https://docplayer.net/7095040-Poisson-processes-chapter-5-5-1-exponential-distribution-the-gamma-function-is-defined-by-g-a-t-a-1-e-t-dt-a-0.html) for Bose-Einstein distribution. The n! suggests this gradually, but is Complexes. Zeta induces Complexes. At most this allows to calculate from one representation of D(n) to other.

Comment: I am sorry, but what do you mean by "why do I expect this to be n?", "The n! suggests this gradually, but is Complexes. ", and what are "this" and "other" in the sentence "At most this allows to calculate from one representation of D(n) to other"? Try to be a little bit coherent in writing.

Comment: In your definition  `IntSer[x_, n_] := `...` you interchange the order of `Series` and `Integrate`. I'm not sure wether that's allowed.

Comment: I bother too. Whether that is allowed or not? Mathematica does it and both are the very same.

Answer (score 1):

Substitution `u=Exp[-t] respectively t=-Log[u]` gives the first term of the asymptotic expansion `x->Infinity` of `Dn[x]`:

```
Integrate[(-Log[u])^n/(u-1),{u,0,1}]-Integrate[(-Log[u])^n/(u-1),{u,0,Exp[-x]}]
```

The first integral evaluates to

```
Integrate[(-Log[u])^n/(u-1),{u,0,1}]
(*-n Gamma[n] PolyLog[1 + n, 1]*)
```

the second integral (hopefully) is of order `O[Exp[-x]]`

Comment: I think this is wrong: `dt=-du/u` so the substitution has to be `(-Log[u])^n/(u(u-1))`!! This stems from `t[u_]:=-Log[u], D[t[u],u] is -1/u`!

Comment: I think this is wrong: `dt=-du/u` so the substitution has to be `(-Log[u])^n/(u(u-1))`!! This stems from `t[u_]:=-Log[u], D[t[u],u] is -1/u`! The partial fraction decomposition is 1/(u(u-1))==-1/u+1/(u-1)!!!

Comment: @SteffenJaeschke Thanks for your reply. Assuming `t[u]==-Log[u]` it follows `dt/du==-1/u`    and `u==Exp[-t]` . The first part equals `dt==-du/u`. Integrand transforms to `(-Log[u])^n/(1/u-1)/(-u)  ` .That's why my answer seems to be right.

Answer (score 0):

`AsymptoticIntegrate` should be the first function to try, but it seems like it kinda struggles for general values of `n`. This works, however, if you give it some time:

```
AsymptoticIntegrate[
 t^2/(Exp[t] - 1),
 {t, 0, x},
 {x, ∞, 2}
]
```